# How to mount a folder to folder in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, mount

I would like to mount the folder `C:\my folder` to `C:\Downloads` in windows seven and both folders are not empty too. I'm not sure is it permitted in windows or not, so I ask to know for sure can I get paired the empty folders? and more can I get paired two non-empty folders?

Answer (score 3):

1. You will lose part of the content, better move out the content first before operation.
2. Download under Favorite is a special folder, you could right click it, and change the target to somewhere else.
3. best way to do pairing is subst.  try to make new drive with it, which make things organized. example:

   subst G: C:\somefolder
4. Consider common use, make a shortcut with mouse then rename it to take out the word shortcut would give best user experience.

Comment: Ok, the Download is a product of mklink /j  operation

Comment: It is actually a file Downloads.lnk under %USERPROFILE%\Links

Comment: you can see where it point to by typing Start Downloads.lnk

Answer (score 2):

In any situation, merging two non-empty folders is dangerous, as you don't really know what happens to the content.

The most clean way to achieve what you want is to create a symbolic link. The situation would be : `C:\Download` is the real directory and `C:\MyFolder` is a link to the first one. Every program will see them as two directories having the same content.

The Wikipedia page explains quite well how to set this up : [here's the link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

Comment: I didn't find yet how to do junction point to non empty dir. windows prevented it

Answer (score 1):

Symlink is definitely the way to go.  I've been using this awesome extension which makes the creating of them really easy!

http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

After you've installed it:

1. Browse to your C:\ in Explorer
2. Right-click the Download directory
3. Select the "Pick link source" option from the menu
4. Right-click some blank space within the C:\ explorer window
5. Choose "Drop as \ Symbolic Link"
6. Done!

Comment: I get solution in the way you designed, but without use of Link Shell Extension. It do the same as windows cmd `mklink /j c:\downloads C:\Users\Yuri\Downloads` I still a bit strugled with fact that i can't make joint point to non-empty directory. mklink demand c:\downloads be an ampty new dir, and i prefer to use the existing folder.